# How can I train Mask-RCNN for a training data having no bounding boxes?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I want to train Mask-RCNN on NYU RGBD dataset, it doesn't contain bounding boxes. I can create myself bounding boxes for the training data but task is too much hectic that too I want to test only the instance segmentation on the input data.So how can I train on training data having no bounding boxes??

Comment: In what format you currently have the annotations...??

Answer (score 1):

Simply you cannot. Object detection algorithms require bounding boxes for training.

Comment: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN, check in this url under the section 'Differences from the Official Paper'.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but not directly you have to cerrer bbox, it is enough to have binary mask [0,1] calculate the length and width of the max (with numpy it's easy) after having the middle coodoner (i, j ) of the mask length / 2 width / 2 and locate the middle of the image on the mask with a deduction of the position with the pixels of the mask.

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the bounding boxes from the instance masks. In the official MaskRCNN code repository, they provided a code for that [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/3deaec5d902d16e1daf56b62d5971d428dc920bc/mrcnn/utils.py#L34).

In short, for a given mask m of shape [h, w]:

```
box = np.zeros([4], dtype=np.int32)
# Bounding box.
horizontal_indicies = np.where(np.any(m, axis=0))[0]
vertical_indicies = np.where(np.any(m, axis=1))[0]
x1, x2 = horizontal_indicies[[0, -1]]
y1, y2 = vertical_indicies[[0, -1]]
# x2 and y2 should not be part of the box. Increment by 1.
x2 += 1
y2 += 1
box = np.array([y1, x1, y2, x2])
```

Comment: Please provide code (at least the important parts) in the answer. Link only answers are not encouraged.